# cost of returning objects in a function for hoisting

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a car object with a drive method. I could do something like this:

```
var car = {
  engine: {
    horsepower: 200,
    weight: 980
  },
  owner: {
    firstName: 'bob',
    lastName: 'tom'
  },
  drive: drive
}

function drive(){
  console.log("vrooom!");
}
```

I'm abstracting implementation of the drive method from the object by leveraging a hoisted function definition. I could also hide "configurations" by just using functions that return objects like so:

```
var car = {
  engine: getEngine(),
  owner: getOwner(),
  drive: drive
}

function drive(){
  console.log("vrooom!");
}

function getEngine(){
  return {
    horsepower: 200,
    weight: 980
  }
}

function getOwner(){
  return {
    firstName: 'bob',
    lastName: 'tom'
  }
}
```

I'm curious what the cost of doing it this way versus the prior, is it marginal?

The reason I ask, is I'm working with angular's UI router, and i'm starting to get lots of states/routes. It would be really nice if I could have all the states listed at top so I can see functionality, without having the developer look through the entire file for the state they're looking for. Keep implementation/functionality searchable, but provide interface to the router at the very top.

What's the difference (memory/speed wise) between:

```
.state('someState', {
  url: 'somePath',
  templateL: 'some content'
}
```

and

```
.state('someState', getSomeStateConfig())

function getSomeStateConfig(){
  return {
    url: 'somePath',
    templateL: 'some content'
  }
}
```

Comment: Individual costs for function calls like that are minuscule and not worth worrying about. If you're doing hundreds of thousands of initializations like that, it might be something to think about.

Comment: Why don't you measure the efficiency with some tests?

Comment: I don't think there would be any measurable performance difference. The real issue is that you need to determine whether you should be using object composition here or object inheritance ("is-a" vs. "has-a").

Comment: @ScottMarcus are you saying build a constructor/class for my state objects?

Comment: also thanks @Pointy duly noted, if you want to post an answer I can check it for you

Comment: In this case, yes. Just because JavaScript doesn't use classical inheritance, it's still and OO programming language and OOP principles still apply.

Comment: Well, let me clarify.. You could build a class/constructor function, but even if you don't and you build a static object, you should still encapsulate all the functions/objects that that object is composed of.

Comment: right, thanks for the help @ScottMarcus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran some code as per @trincot

```
var time = new Date()
for (var i = 1; i < 10000000; i++){
  var car = {
    engine: getEngine(),
    owner: getOwner(),
    drive: drive
  }

  function drive(){
    console.log("vrooom!");
  }

  function getEngine(){
    return {
      horsepower: 200,
      weight: 980
    }
  }

  function getOwner(){
    return {
      firstName: 'bob',
      lastName: 'tom'
    }
  }
}

var secondTime = new Date()

console.log(' first: ', secondTime - time);
```

vs

```
var time = new Date()

for (var i = 1; i < 10000000; i++){
  var car = {
    engine: {
      horsepower: 200,
      weight: 980
    },
    owner: {
      firstName: 'bob',
      lastName: 'tom'
    },
    drive: drive
  }

  function drive(){
    console.log("vrooom!");
  }

}

var secondTime = new Date()
console.log(' first: ', secondTime - time);
```

ten million was when I started to get a difference of 1.2 seconds. At 1 million It was difference of ~140ms. At 100,000 It was ~13 ms difference